# How do i hide a query string from google index?

Tags: javascript, seo, robots.txt

I am currently creating a small info site for a product that will be used by two companies
unfortunately the two companies cannot agree on what content to display as they are from different fields, so I have devised a method of using query strings to display the relevant information.

upon page load the user is prompted with a question of which sector is most relevant to them then the page is reloaded with a query string (www.page.com?id=company1 or www.page.com=company2) which is then interpreted with JavaScript and the correct content is then displayed.

but if one choice is more popular to the user eg "company1" I don't want Google to index page?id=comapny1 over the standard no query page. or index both of them and users choose the wrong one. as the user needs to choose when they enter the site to deter unbiased sales

how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/IOww4AnTKZs

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the canonical tag is the solution. But if you want to hide this content from Google you will not rank for it.